# Does `Toast.MakeText` produce output in all activities?

Tags: android, toast

I'd like to make some text via `Toast` inside  message handler, and my message handler is declared in the separate class.

```
public class HandlerAlert extends Handler {
      final static byte IP_OK=0;
      final static byte IP_WRONG=-1;
      Context ctx;

    public HandlerAlert(Context ctx) {
        super();
        this.ctx=ctx;
    }


    public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
            case IP_OK:
                if (msg.arg1==(CheckSendMode.REGULAR).ordinal())
                {
                    Toast.makeText(ctx/*null*/,   
                        "OK",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.i("MessageOk",ctx.getClass().getName());
                }
........
```

I have two activities, and both can call this message. I expected that my `Toast.MakeText` would produce output in the activity which context (parameter `ctx`) is used. However, I see the output in both activities despite of `ctx` passed. Name of activity passed in `Context ctx` is observed by `Log.i("MessageOk",ctx.getClass().getName());` I thought that `Toast.MakeText` works in all activities despite of context, and even tested null context (absolutely expected exception was obtained). 
My question is the following: does `Toast.MakeText` send output in the activity which is currently open? I'm ready to provide any part of code if necessary.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Toast message is not related to your current Activity context if your Toast is triggered and Activity closed , But Toast must be shown.

Comment: Chetan, thanks for a quick reply. Both my activities are previously created, but one of them is current (on the screen), and this activity always catch `Toast` output, despite of context passed..

Answer (score 0):

Create a class ShowToast
inside that class create a method

```
public Class ShowToast{
 Context mContext;
 public void displayToast(String msg){
 Toast.makeText(mContext,msg,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Inside your activity

```
ShowToast dispToast = new ShowToast(this);

btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
 publiv void onClick(View v){
  dispToast.showToast("Hello World");
}
});
```

Answer (score -1):

It is hypothesis only: I suppose that in fact `toast`uses application context, not activity one. I try
    Toast.makeText(ctx.getApplicationContext(), "OK",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
and it works as if it would be activity context. By the way,

```
Log.i("MessageOk",ctx.getApplicationContext().getClass().getName());
```

produces class `android.app.Application`. Please confirm or deny my supposition.

Comment: The person(s) who downvoted both answers are kindly asked to suggest his/her/their one.